# Add to cart button in related products leads to some view source page

Tags: related-products

I am bit new to magento am facing an issue.i added add to cart button to related product but when cliks on it it open a new page showing a source code of something.am adding a screen shot

[![Page shown after clinking add to cart button in related
 products][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW3eY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW3eY.png)

also when i check cart the product is added really.
My add to cart button on home page is working fine

my related.phtml code is as follows

```
     <ol class="mini-products-list list-inline media-ol products-grid" id="block-related">
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>" style="min-height: 407px;">
         <!--<?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                 <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                     <input type="checkbox" style="position: relative; right: -74px; top: 40px;" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" ame="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                 <?php endif; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>-->
             <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(200) ?>"  alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name media-pdt"><a style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <!--<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php  echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?><br/>
                    -->
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"<?php if($_item->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>> 
                            <div class="btn-med-add"><div style="text-align: center;">
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart');?>"><button type="submit"  title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="btnbtn-success" ><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle; ?></span></span>Add To Cart</button></a>
                             </div>
                         </form>
                    </div>            
                </div>
             </div>
    </li>
   <?php endforeach ?>
 </ol>
```

Please can any help

My add to cart js file code is as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('.item button').on('click', function () {         //alert('what');
    jQuery('#mini-cart').load(document.URL +  ' #mini-cart');

        var cart = jQuery('#custom-cart');      //alert(this.value);
        var imgtodrag = jQuery(this).parents('.item').find("img").eq(0);

        if (imgtodrag) {
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
               .offset({
                   top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                   left: imgtodrag.offset().left
                })
               .css({
                 'opacity': '0.5',
                 'position': 'absolute',
                 'height': '150px',
                 'width': '150px',
                 'z-index': '100'
               })
               .appendTo(jQuery('body'))
               .animate({
                  'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                  'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                  'width': 75,
                  'height': 75
                }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

            setTimeout(function () {
                 cart.effect("shake", {
                      times: 2
                 }, 200);
             }, 1500);

             imgclone.animate({
                 'width': 0,
                 'height': 0
             }, function () {
                  jQuery(this).detach()
             });

          }
     }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you have an extension for adding products to cart via AJAX.
This means your `addAction` from the cart controller is rewritten.
Either disable the extension or find out the js function that should be called when adding a product to cart and apply it to the related products add to cart button.
That function should handle the AJAX response and update the dom elements related to the cart.
**[EDIT]**
Your code does not work because the selector that triggers the ajax is `.item button` but your link is an `a` tag.
Add a class on the link to the cart. let's say `add-to-cart` like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart');?>"><button type="submit"  title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="btnbtn-success add-to-cart" ><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle; ?></span></span><?php echo $this->__('Add To Cart')?></button></a>
```

and modify the js making the first line look like this:

```
jQuery('.item button, .add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
```

Comment: yes i am using extension fly to cart .i disabled it but still receiving same page ..i have updated the js file code above

Comment: @YousafAli. see my update.

Comment: i did the changes ,still getting the same error,But my function do calls when i un-comment alert('hello'); then gives alert it means function do call.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using magento 2, you can try to use this extension to smooth fly effect of product image, after you add product to cart:
https://marketplace.magento.com/adam-flytocart.html